# Limit of the given function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Please help me out with this limit given below-

## \begin{equation}
\operatorname{Lim}_{x \rightarrow 0^+}(\sin x)^{x}
\end{equation}

I tried the following substitution-

\begin{equation}
x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}-x
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Lim}_{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \frac{(\cos x)^{\pi / 2}}{(\cos x)^{x}}
\end{equation}
Which is of the form zero/zero so tried to apply L'Hospital's Rule but didn't reach to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try the old exponential-log trick by writing it as: $\exp(x\log(\sin(x)))$. Now carry the limit inside the exponential.